# "Preload" apple-touch-precomposed-icon before adding to home screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile-safari

Is there any way to "preload" the apple-touch-precomposed-icon so that is already loaded before it is addded to the homescreen? As it stands right now (from what I've seen), you tap "Add to Home Screen" from Safari, and it uses a screenshot of the page until the icon is downloaded. I assume this is to preserve bandwidth upon page load.

I've tried to include it as an `img` on the page in hopes of it being cached, but that didn't seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I've always wondered this too. Seems odd that it doesn't appear to cache it even if you put it in an `img`...

Answer (score -2):

```html
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.tagebisweihnachten.ch/pictures/apple-touch-icon-57x57x.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="http://www.tagebisweihnachten.ch/pictures/apple-touch-icon-72x72x.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="http://www.tagebisweihnachten.ch/pictures/apple-touch-icon-114x114x.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="http://www.tagebisweihnachten.ch/pictures/apple-touch-icon-144x144x.png" />
```

Set 4 icons with different sizes. Your iDevice choose the picture and sets it as the App-icon.

This is my Page for example, I'm still working^^

Comment: the sizez are wrong now they've changed : https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2